# Setting up Splunk alerting

Tags: splunk, splunk-formula

Is there a way to monitor that data is received regularly, and alert when out of compliance?

I would love to setup alerting for our GCP and Azure environmennts.

Answer (score 1):

If you have sufficient data from GCP and Azure coming into Splunk then, yes, it's possible.

Start by creating a search to determine if you are out of compliance.  Once you are satisfied with the search, click Save As and choose Alert.  Complete the form, save, and you're done.

Comment: Im like a newbie do splunk offer searches for the stuff that's out of compliance or would I have to look for that in GCP or AWS?

Comment: It's up to you to define what "out of compliance" means, determine what data tells you if you are in/out of compliance, and develop a search for that data.  We can help with the last part.